# Loop array and check if previous field is same as current PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, for-loop

I have a CSV file which I am reading in using PHP. It is a comma delimited CSV file which splits each line of data into an array. The array in this case is `$fields`. After all the processing is done, the arrays are then spit out as an XML file.

The `$fields[ 0 ]` contains a reference number for each line. Some lines may have the same reference number indicating that items are together so the `$total_gross_weight` will be the value of the current reference + the next reference.

I have a for loop which goes over the arrays and processes them.

**For Loop**

```
//set variable to empty

    $previous_consignee_id = "";
    $total_gross_weight    = 0;
    $total_volume          = 0;
    $total_net_weight      = 0;


//for loop to loop over arrays
 for( $counter = 0; $counter < count( $buffer ); $counter++ ) {

     //$fields is the array, split with a comma
     $fields = split( ",", $buffer[ $counter ] );

     //set consignee_id as the first field in each array
     //example of consignee_id = DUN72049214
     $consignee_id = trim( $fields[ 0 ] );

     //if the consignee_id is not equal to $previous_consignee_id
     //and $previous_consignee_id is not empty
     if( $consignee_id  != $previous_consignee_id ) {

         //set $total_gross_weight to fields[ 60 ]
         //$fields[ 60 ] is always the weight
         $total_gross_weight = $fields[ 60 ];

         //run create_job method
         //this method works fine so no changes needed to it
         create_job( $xml, $fields, $total_gross_weight );

         echo "creating new job ".$consignee_id." weight is ".$total_gross_weight."\n";

     } else {

         //if the $consignee_id matches the previous_consignee_id
         //total_gross_weight is the current $total_gross_weight + $fields[ 60 ]
         $total_gross_weight = $total_gross_weight + $fields[ 60 ];

         echo "same job ".$consignee_id." weight is ".$total_gross_weight."\n";

     }

     //set $previous_consignee_id to the current $consignee_id;
     $previous_consignee_id = $consignee_id;


 }//endfor
```

**Result of For Loop**

```
creating new job DN1234567 weight is 500
creating new job DN1234568 weight is 500
same job DN1234568 weight is 1000
creating new job DN1234569 weight is 500
creating new job DN1234570 weight is 500
creating new job DN1234571 weight is 500
creating new job DN1234572 weight is 500
same job DN1234572 weight is 1000
same job DN1234572 weight is 1500
creating new job DN1234573 weight is 500
creating new job DN1234574 weight is 500
creating new job DN1234575 weight is 500
same job DN1234575 weight is 1000
creating new job DN1234576 weight is 500
creating new job DN1234577 weight is 500
same job DN1234577 weight is 1000
creating new job DN1234578 weight is 500
creating new job DN1234579 weight is 500
creating new job DN1234580 weight is 500
```

The issue is that the very first job ( DN1234567 ) is echoing out as "same job". However, since it is the very first one, it should be echoing out as a "New job". As you can see, when the job reference is same as the previous one, the weight is totalled together to combine it into one. However, the following job after that has an incorrect value as it seems to carry the "same job" value over.

I have tried un-setting the variables after each iteration but I cant seem to figure it out. I believe there is an issue with the condition of the If statement as in the first iteration the "previous_consignee_id " is empty which results in it skipping to the else statement.

Can anyone please give me some pointers as to how I can resolve this issue.

[CSV file to test](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byz5i73jQ1fkM2hjREktQnJIRWc)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in if statement in if you have condition that `$previous_consignee_id != ""` which will become false first iteration as you have assign `""` at starting so remove it

```
if( $consignee_id  != $previous_consignee_id  && $previous_consignee_id != "" ) {
```

To

```
if( $consignee_id  != $previous_consignee_id) {
```

**EDIT**

In if also you are displaying value `$total_gross_weight` of before assigning it. SO change your code to

```
if( $consignee_id  != $previous_consignee_id) {

         //run create_job method
         //this method works fine so no changes needed to it
         create_job( $xml, $fields, $total_gross_weight );

          //set $total_gross_weight to fields[ 60 ]
         //$fields[ 60 ] is always the weight
         $total_gross_weight = $fields[ 60 ];

         echo "creating new job ".$consignee_id." weight is ".$total_gross_weight."\n";



     }
```

Comment: I have tried this and it still dosent work. It changes the first iteration to "creating new job" but the value is 0 as there is no $total_gross_weight. The issue of the values being carried over from the same job to the new job still persists even after your code change.

Comment: check uodated answer

Comment: Half way there! This seems to have fixed the issue of the $total_gross_weight being carried over to the next new job (most stupid and silly mistake Ive made - see updated post for latest echo ). The issue that still persists is that in the XML, the first iteration shows up but with the weight being as "0". After checking the rest of the output, it seems that all the weights need to be shifted up one position.